# Session variable no updating

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have two php pages

page1.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
     ?
  <script>
  function request(){
  $.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: 'page2.php',
  success: function(data) {
     alert(<?php echo $_SESSION['value'];?>);
  },    
    complete: function() {
   setTimeout(function(){request();}, 2000); 
   }
   });
   };
   </script>
```

page2.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['value'] = //Assign a random value.//
    echo $_SESSION['value'];
     ?>
```

The problem is everytime Ajax is called page2.php echos the current "$_SESSION['value']" value. But in page1.php alert shows the old "$_SESSION['value']" value unless i refresh the page, after which it shows current value untill Ajax is been called again and the value gets updated. I have no clue as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think for a second: when is your `<? ?>` executed? When your html code with your script is rendered **on server side**. That means, it is a constant unless you refresh your page - when you get another constant. You should render the value into the response of page2 on the server side - and echo the `data` you got.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing! but then again if i could just echo the value i wouldn't have called a session variable on the first place.

Comment: Yes! Look at your html code, and notice that the value is already there. Because you don't return anything from the server and you don't display what's returned.

Comment: Just try `success: function(data) {
     alert(data);
  }`

Comment: This is not the actual code. i returned the value in the real one. Im just using this to explain my question and i got the answer